# The multi-part identifier "itemDetail.BillDate" could not be bound

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

```
SELECT DISTINCT  [Billlist].[billno] [Bill No.],temp.[BillDate] [Date],[Billlist].[user] [Customer Name],[Billlist].[total] Total,[paid] Paid,[discount] Discount 
           FROM temp  
           JOIN [Billlist]  ON temp.[billno]=[Billlist].[billno] 
          WHERE itemDetail.[BillDate]  BETWEEN '9/19/2014' and '9/19/2014'
```

What can i do?

I need to filter but if i'm using i got that error!!!

Any one reply me as soon as possible.

Comment: You are trying to use a table reference which is not exists in the query. Use the `itemDetail` as an alias, or add the table to the `FROM` clause (join it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless `itemDetail.[BillDate]`should really be `temp.[BillDate]`in the where clause you need to join the `itemdetail` table with the appropriate table.

Based on the column names I'm guessing your query should look like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT  
    [Billlist].[billno] [Bill No.],
    temp.[BillDate] [Date],
    [Billlist].[user] [Customer Name],
    [Billlist].[total] Total,
    [paid] Paid,
    [discount] Discount 
FROM temp  
JOIN [Billlist] ON temp.[billno] = [Billlist].[billno] 
WHERE temp.[BillDate] BETWEEN '9/19/2014' and '9/19/2014'
```